# Fibonacci function list

Tags: python, list, function, fibonacci

I am currently doing a part of my assignment i have to make it so if the user enters 10 in function 
the answer should be

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

but my program results in

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

This is my program

```
def fib(n):
    fibonacci = []
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(n):
        fibonacci.append(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return fibonacci
```

Comment: Just append 0 to the list or initialize it as fibonacci = [0] than run the loop till range(n-1). Return an empty list if n == 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to append a instead of b.

```
def fib(n):
    fibonacci = []
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(n):
        fibonacci.append(a)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return fibonacci
```

Results for `print(fib(10))`

```
> python fib.py
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Comment: wow lol i feel dumb thanks for help i will pick it as answer in 11 minutes when it lets me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem.  Also note the change I made to your original code in the question.  Having your check for n at the end of the function will never work because it has already returned.  If you wanted to return early you would need to do your length check before.  However, in this case a 0 will not run the range loop and you end up with an empty list as desired.